# relations using JPA persistent

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I would like to know if there is relations between two entity's for instance **salesOrder** entity and **SalesOrderItem** with relation **one to many**
how should i persist them,i.e. do i need to keep the order  and relations or there is a way to 
divide the persist and first for example start with sales order item and than the sales order.
this is just example, i want to know if there is a way to **ignore the relation** during the persistence with the JPA
and persist the object without any needs to refer to the relations,but of course if there is foreign key provide it at  a time

Comment: I don't understand anything about your question. Please provide some code.

Comment: I ask about the concept if I can directly put data for entity x without any concern about the relation for entity y.why did you vote down?

Comment: I ask about the concept if I can directly put data for entity x without any concern about the relation for entity y for example if i directly put the data to the DB i dont need to be concern about the relation between them.why did you vote down?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to persist them as follows:

1. Establish all links between the two entities; if child references parent, set that reference.  If parent references child(ren), set that/those references.
2. Persist the two entities.  If one (parent) references another (child), the relationship can be marked with `Cascade.PERSIST` to allow the references to be followed during the persist operation - in this case you would only need to persist the one.

You asked " is a way to divide the persist and first for example start with sales order item and than the sales order".  Since the item would generally reference it's containing order, it's difficult to imagine any reasonable scenario where you would persist the item prior to the order.  That you're asking these kinds of questions with so little demonstrated understanding of issues, I'd take the position that you're not really ready to address the exceptions that might (or might not) allow them to work for you.  Best to stick with proper practices.

Creating an order first (The 'one' in @OneToMany) may be appropriate, even if the order contains a `List` or `Map` of child items - as long as the item entities contain the specific references to the order.  In a given "unit of work" (entity manager session), you'll still want to update the parent's list/map as you add/create and persist additional children.

Comment: @Richard-Thanks for your answer,maybe i try to explain myself better. what we are trying to develop is java api that get list of class (classes names - which is entitys) dynamically (can be any) and i need to build the entity's with reflection and for the type add data from file (we are creating api that create mock data for entitys from file) and when i do reflection i have inside the entity class member referance to another class and my question is if i must to build it than or i can proceed and when finish to persist entity a start with entity b ,